# An extension to $2^{\omega}$

Tags: general-topology

The Cantor space $2^\omega = [0] \cup  [10] \cup [110] \cup [1110] \cup\cdots\cup\{(1,1,1,1,\ldots)\},$ where $[0]= \{x \in2^\omega:x_1 = 0\}$, $[10]= \{x \in 2^\omega: x_1 = 1 \wedge x_2 = 0\}\ldots$ etc. Name $ A_{0} = [0], A_{1} = [10], A_{2} = [110], A_3 = [1110],\ldots$ etc.  Let $f_{n}:A_{n} \rightarrow 2^\omega$ be continuous(homeomorphism if you wish) for each $n =0,1,2,3,\ldots$.Define $f:2^\omega -\{(1,1,1,1,\ldots)\}\rightarrow 2^{\omega}$ by $f = f_{n}(x)$ if $x \in A_{n}$. Then f is continuous on $2^{\omega}-\{(1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)\} .$
How can I extend it to $2^{\omega}$? Where should the point $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ be sent so the 
extension can be continuous?

I have the feeling that if such extension exists then that point must be sent to itself or to
(0,0,0,...)

Comment: What does your notation mean? What are $[0],[10]$, etc?

Comment: Since $(1,1,1,\dots)$ is the limit of the sequence whose $n$-th term consists of $n$ ones followed by an infinite string of zeros, you do not have much choice.

Comment: Unless the $f_n$'s are chosen with considerable care, there may well be no continuous extension of $f$ to $2^\omega$.

Comment: @ Andres,$[0]$ = sequences with first digit $0, [01] =$ all sequences with fisrt 2 digits 0,1,.....and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $f_{n}(A_{n}) \subset A_{n}$, then define $f:2^\omega\rightarrow 2^\omega$ by $$ 
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f_{n}(x) & \quad x \in A_{n} \\
            (1,1,1,...) & \quad x = (1,1,1,...)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Then $f$ is an extension to the $f$ in the question. Let $U$ be any basic open set in $2^\omega$
s.th. $(1,1,1,...) \notin U $ then $f^{-1}(U)$ = $\bigcup f_{n}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $2^\omega$. If $(1,1,1,...) \in U $, then $U = \{x \in 2^\omega: m-string (1,1,1,...,1)\subset x\}$ = all sequences with first m digits $1's$. So, in this case $U = \bigcup_{n = m}^{\infty} A_{n} \cup \{(1,1,1,...)\}$ and $f^{-1}(U) = U.$ Thus $f$ is a continuous extension to that $f.$